# The usage of "it is recalled that"

Tags: word-usage

My professor (whose first language is not English) keeps adding "It is recalled that" at the start of different sentences describing facts/products.

I do not think it is used appropriately.

What do you think?

Example:

> It is recalled that this technique has the following advantages: bla
>   bla bla...

I think this kind of usage implies, falsely, that I have mentioned the *advantages* in a previous section/paragraph.

Comment: Ehm... I'm not even sure what he's trying to say. It's not correct anyway.

Comment: To be pedantic, you can conjure constructs where this would be correct, e.g. after someone is reminded that birds can fly, but I'm certain that's not what the prof is talking about.

Comment: This is generally speaking, a **nosism**; your professor is injecting the voice of **[the "authorial we"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/188705/55623)**, common in pedagogy and academia generally.

Comment: I suspect that he means something like "You will recall that...".  This is a common idiom which would imply that he expects you to be aware of the stated fact, even if he has not just discussed it.

Comment: I interpret it as an awkward, stilted, passive voice variation of "As I recall," "As far as I can recall," or "I seem to recall."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of construction is common in academia, in two contexts: proofs and pedagogy.

The phrase *it is [to be] recalled that* or *we must recall* is an example of *nosism*: atypical uses (or implications) of "we" for rhetorical purposes.

The *royal we* (*We are not amused! Off with his head!*) is one example of nosism, and here we have another: the ***author's we***.  From the [Wikipedia article on nosism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We#Atypical_uses_of_we):

> Similar to the *editorial we* is the practice .. of referring to a generic third person by we [for example], "By adding three and five, we obtain eight.", "We are thus led also to a definition of 'time' in physics.". *We* in this sense often refers to "the reader and the author", *since the **author often assumes that the reader knows [agrees with] certain principles***.

Here, the *certain principles* are whatever follows the "it is to be recalled that": i.e. your professor expects your readers to *know* or agree with whatever principle is being outlined, but may simply need a reminder.

As to why he's doing it: such constructions (a) tend to make a writeup more clinical, they somewhat distance the author from the text, give it more of a "I'm just the messenger relaying an established fact" feeling, and (b) if whatever follows "it is to be recalled that" is trivial or expected knowledge among your readership, then it also serves to soften any implications of questioning their intelligence by "stating the obvious".

As to whether it's good writing... well, I can't say more than "don't overdo it", but of course it is to be recalled that the man controls your GPA.

<sub>PS: Generally speaking in recent quarters, I've been too lazy to post many answers, but since you were kind enough to take my advice on a separate question in good faith, I feel I owe you this courtesy. Welcome to the site. *We* do hope you'll stick around.</sub>

Comment: Cool answer! It is both informative and fun to read. Thank you.

Comment: @HappyBee No problem. Glad you liked it. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's grammatically wrong, but it is stylistically weak.

Why say, "It is recalled that so-and-so is such-and-such," when you can more concisely and forcefully say, "So-and-so is such-and-such."

It's simpler and clearer.

Comment: Quite frankly, I think the cited usage is worse than "stylistically weak" - it just comes across to me as *ignorant*. According to Google Books estimates, over 2/3rds of all hits for [*it is recalled that*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+is+recalled+that%22) occur as [***when** it is recalled that*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22when+it+is+recalled+that%22) (which latter *doesn't* seem unreasonable to me). Who does OP's prof think the implied subject in the passive should be? Himself? The reader? Or some other unspecified person or people?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Precisely, "the reader, or some other unspecified person or people". It is known that this is a common rhetorical tactic used to lend a gloss of disinterested clinicality or professionalism to one's writing.

Comment: @Dan: I think there's a *huge* difference between *it is known that [whatever point you wish to raise is known to some unspecified people, possibly including both speaker and audience]* and ***recalled***. It makes no sense to mention what people who *aren't* involved in the discourse might "recall", since they have no context within which to bring anything to mind. Nor is it natural for the speaker to be referencing the *audience*, since that would be expressed as ***you will** recall that...* It's just a dumb-ass way of saying ***I** recall that...* which is a pointless observation anyway.